# What's the difference between CheckBoxList Items and TableRows when dynamically rendered in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, page-lifecycle, dynamic-controls

I'm working on slightly changing the functionality of a page in an ASP.Net website. In the original page there was a checkbox list written into the page with no items hard coded.

Instead on the initial render the cbl gets databound to the results of a query thus:

```
sSQL = "select query here";

using (SqlConnection dbcon = new DataAccess().OpenDb())
{
     using (SqlDataReader dr = new SqlCommand(sSQL, dbcon).ExecuteReader())
     {
          cbl.DataTextField = "description";
          cbl.DataValueField = "productid";
          cbl.DataSource = dr;
          cbl.DataBind();
     }
     dbcon.Close();
}
```

On a postback the following code:

```
foreach (ListItem li in cbl.Items) { if (li.Selected) rtnQS += li.Value + ","; }
```

Happily goes through the dynamic databound list items in the checkbox list and retrieves the checked values. I tried to do the same thing, putting an empty table on the page and then creating the rows dynamically:

```
sSQL = "similar select query here";

using (SqlConnection dbcon = new DataAccess().OpenDb())
{
    using (SqlDataReader dr = new SqlCommand(sSQL, dbcon).ExecuteReader())
    {
       while (dr.Read())
       {
           TableRow tr = new TableRow();

           TableCell tc = new TableCell();

           CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();

           chk.Text = dr["description"].ToString();
           chk.InputAttributes.Add("id", dr["id"].ToString());
           chk.Checked = true;

           tc.Controls.Add(chk);

           TableCell tc2 = new TableCell();

           if (Convert.ToBoolean(dr["controlcondition"]))
           {
                CheckBoxList cbl_sub = new CheckBoxList();
                cbl_sub.Attributes.Add("for", dr["id"].ToString());
                sSQL = "subquery";
                using (SqlConnection newcon = new DataAccess().OpenDb())
                {
                   using (SqlDataReader br = new SqlCommand(sSQL, newcon).ExecuteReader())
                   {
                       cbl_block.DataTextField = "subname";
                       cbl_block.DataValueField = "subid";
                       cbl_block.DataSource = br;
                       cbl_block.DataBind();
                   }
                }

                tc2.Controls.Add(cbl_sub);
           }
           else
           {
              TextBox txtSub = new TextBox();
              txtSub.Attributes.Add("for", dr["id"].ToString());

              tc2.Controls.Add(txtSub);
           }

           tr.Cells.Add(tc);
           tr.Cells.Add(tc2);

           tblDispatchOpt.Rows.Add(tr);
        }
    }

    dbcon.Close();
}
```

The only problem is that when the iterator comes to the table it only reads the hard coded header row. (The table renders beautifully with all the correct attributes on the original page though.)

Here's the bit of code that tries to read the table rows:

```
foreach (TableRow row in tblDispatchOpt.Rows)
{
      TableCell cell = row.Cells[0];

      ++counter;

      foreach (Control c in cell.Controls)
      {
           if (c is CheckBox)
           {
               CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)c;
               if (cb.Checked && cb.Attributes["ttid"] != null) dtTTInfo.Rows.Add(cb.Attributes["ttid"].ToString(), "", "");
           }
      }
}
```

Except that a debugging label check happily tells me there's only one row and it's the hard coded header row. So essentially doesn't read the other rows as it seems the page doesn't believe they exist when it comes to read them.

So why doesn't it work with the table? Or, if it doesn't work with the table for the usual reason that things don't work with dynamic controls on postbacks e.g. rendering, lifecycle etc., *why does it work with the checkboxlist?*

Comment: Post the code that does not work.  Showing your code that does work does not help us know what your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to recreate dynamic controls on every postback if you want to get values from them.
You should do that in CreateChildControls() method.

Comment: Cool, that helps a bit. However, I did specifically ask why didn't the original coder have to do that with the checkboxlist? If I knew that I'm sure it would help a great deal. I am modifying someone else's code and their stuff still all works, it's the modification that doesn't.

Comment: On further consideration it is pretty vital to know why it will work with the checkboxlist because to implement the CreateChildControls method I will have to alter the current functionality in addition to the new. I don't want to break anything unless I can explain why I had to.

Comment: CheckboxList was put there as static control, but populated dynamically, right?

Comment: Yes. The table is too only the rows are dynamic.

Comment: So again - it is problem with recreating controls: checkboxlist is one control and it is created always, so after postback you get any information about changes in it. Table on postback exists, but it is ampty and you have to first recreate its content in your code. To get information from dynamic control you have to recreate it always.

Comment: Okay, but isn't each ListItem in the CBL's list a separate control in and of itself? I still don't get how it can see dynamically created Listitems in a static but empty CBL but not see dynamically created rows in a static but empty table control. Never mind.

Comment: checkboxlist recreate items internally like each databound control, but if you use table - then you have to implement your own functionality because it is not databound control;

Comment: Ahhhhh. I understand. Right. Well, annoying, but at least clear. Thanks.